# How to load all images in a folder into HTML

Tags: php, html, ajax

I am looking to load all images from specific folders into my website. Currently, I have to copy and paste this HTML code and change each individual file name. Is there a way that I can dynamically load each image into this same HTML?

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="item__content">
        <img src="img/Underwater/1.jpg" alt="img02" />
        <h3 class="item__title">Retro irony sartorial <span class="item__date">05/05/2015</span></h3>
        <div class="item__details">
            <ul>
                <li><i class="icon icon-camera"></i><span>Canon PowerShot S95</span></li>
                <li><i class="icon icon-focal_length"></i><span>22.5 mm</span></li>
                <li><i class="icon icon-aperture"></i><span>&fnof;/5.6</span></li>
                <li><i class="icon icon-exposure_time"></i><span>1/1000</span></li>
                <li><i class="icon icon-iso"></i><span>80</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean you need to change `img` `src` attribute?

Comment: Yes, but essentially I want to loop through the images and not have to keep copying pasting the same HTML

Comment: Do you need PHP in particular? Script written in any language could generate you this HTML. Also, any language including PHP has a tutorial on looping over files in directory.

Comment: Have you tried using scandir()?

Comment: You can generate this HTML code using any language and put your filenames there. We need a bit more description.

Answer (score 1):

This while use glob to search for jpgs within your designated file path. Just change the file extension (if needed) and the image folder that you are pulling the images from.

```html
<?php 
$directory = "imagepath";
$images = glob($directory . "/*.jpg");

foreach($images as $image)
{
  echo "<img src=".$image.">";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to do it using only plain HTML, that won't be possible.

To load all you images dynamically, you'd have to use server-side code, PHP or Javascript (through Node.js for example).